# Hibernate criteria search

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to create a DAO method  public List search(String parameter) where it should return all Projects whose Description contains the parameter String.

this is what i have now:

```
@Override
public List<Project> search(String parameter) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    List<Project> projects = session.createCriteria(Project.class).add(Restrictions.eq("description",parameter)).list();
    return projects;
}
```

Anyone care to help? Thank you!

Comment: What's your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will help you.

List projects = session.createCriteria(Project.class).add(Restrictions.like("description", parameter, MatchMode.ANYWHERE);

Comment: Yes, It did! Thank you very much